# How do I retrieve localStorage data on React app start and store it in Redux using useEffect? (It keeps wiping out my data)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Edit: perhaps I should not combine React hooks and mapStateToProps in the same application, but instead use the Redux hooks (useSelector, etc)?

In my React application I have an array of 'friend' data in Redux.  I am using `useEffect` in one of my components to store this data to browser localStorage every time it changes.

```
// 'friends' is an array from Redux store,
// storeManyFriends is an action creator that will store to Redux
  const {friends, storeManyFriends} = props;

// store 'friends' to local storage each time it changes
useEffect(() => {
    try {
      persistData(friends,'my friends') // stores to local storage
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error persisting data',e.message)
    }
  }, [friends]);
```

I want to load that data from localStorage when the app starts (if it exists) and store it in Redux using `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
// get stored 'friends' from local storage on component mount
    const storedFriends = retrievePersistedData('my friends') 
    if (storedFriends) {
      try {
        storeManyFriends(storedFriends)
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error retrieving data',e.message)
      }
    }
   }, []);
```

The problem is that it seems that when the app restarts, the first `useEffect` is getting called with an empty `friends` array, which is then stored to localStorage, wiping out what's there. I could check for whether the array is empty before I store it, but sometimes the array will be empty because someone has no friends and I would want to store that empty value.  What is the best way to handle this?

For reference, the Redux store initial state would be

```
export const originalState = {
  friends: [],
};
```

Comment: Are you using browser localStorage to Store data?

Comment: @Sanjiv, yes I am

Comment: After fetching from localStorage, you have to set friends state using dispatch({type: 'SET_FRIEND', payload: localStorage.get('saved_friend')})

Comment: If I am correct you want to update the local store only when the friend's array change. Instead of calling use effect to update it, call `persistData(friends)` when you fire the update friends action for the store. Does that makes sense? This was you can escape the issue of it resetting on every boot because the redux store will be empty

Comment: @Dimensionless -- Yes, I did it that way originally, thanks.  I just saw an example that used `useEffect` and it seemed elegant, so I thought I'd try that.  I think, as per my edit above, that maybe then one should use only hooks -- like `useSelector`.  I will go back to what you suggested.

Comment: You can do one thing, set `friends` in the state to `friends: ''` instead of `friends: []`, and in `useEffect` add a condition so that it doesn't update the localStorage if it is `friends: ''` as that would mean nothing have changed. Does that help

Comment: @Dimensionless, Perfect, that worked!

Comment: @Cerulean kudos

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 scenarios:

- no key in localStorage
- empty array
- array with data

When you fetch, create the empty array first if it doesn't yet exist. This will ensure that when you save you always have a key (with an empty array).

Comment: can you explain in a more detailed manner?  The issue I am having is that the `useEffect` hook is storing the empty array from the Redux store when the application boots. Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're saying...